# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Credentials'

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, service, cloud, account

I'm trying to use a service account directly from a python script with the need to have a json file path that contains the service account but I keep running into this error, btw I'm trying to run my code via a flask app.

Here is the flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# from google.oauth2 import service_account
import json
# import os
import pandas as pd

# Create the app object
app = Flask(__name__)


# importing function for calculations
from Record_Matching import Matching


@app.route("/query", methods = ['get'])
def query():

    params = request.json
    # query1 = request.args.get('query1', type = str)
    # query2 = request.args.get('query2', type = str)
    # querycolumns = request.args.get('querycolumns')
    
    # project_id = request.args.get('project_id', type = str)
    # service_account = request.args.get('service_account')
    # SS = request.args.get('SS', type = float)
    # TT = request.args.get('TT', type = float)
    result = Matching(params['query1'],params['query2'], params['SS'],params['TT'], params['service_account'], params['project_id'], params['querycolumns'])

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8080, debug=True)
```

this is my function source:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
import recordlinkage
from recordlinkage.preprocessing import phonetic
import uuid
from uuid import uuid4
import random
import string
import json
import os


# Results to data frame function
def gcp2df(sql, client):
    query = client.query(sql)
    results = query.result()
    return results.to_dataframe()
# Exporting df to bigquery - table parameter example: "dataset.tablename"
# def insert(df, table):
#     client = bigquery.Client()
#     job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(write_disposition=bigquery.job.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
#     return client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, table, job_config = job_config)

def pair(df1, df2, TT, querycolumns):
    
    # function to take pair from list and compare:
    L = querycolumns
    l=len(querycolumns)
    p1=0
    p2=1

    # To generate phonetics we  need to make sure all names are in english. 
    # thus we'll replace non-english words by random english strings
    df1[L[p1]] = df1[L[p1]].astype(str)
    df2[L[p2]] = df2[L[p2]].astype(str)
    for i in range(0,len(df1)):
        if df1[L[p1]][i].isascii() == False:
            df1[L[p1]][i] = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5))

    for i in range(0,len(df2)):
        if df2[L[p2]][i].isascii() == False:
            df2[L[p2]][i] = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=5))


    compare = recordlinkage.Compare()
    df1["phonetic_given_name"] = phonetic(df1[L[p1]], "soundex")
    df2["phonetic_given_name"] = phonetic(df2[L[p2]], "soundex")
    df1["initials"] = (df1[L[p1]].str[0]  + df1[L[p1]].str[-1])
    df2["initials"] = (df2[L[p2]].str[0]  + df2[L[p2]].str[-1])
    indexer = recordlinkage.Index()
    indexer.block('initials')
    candidate_links = indexer.index(df1, df2)
    compare.exact('phonetic_given_name', 'phonetic_given_name', label="phonetic_given_name")
    # O(n) a function that uses two pointers to track consecutive pairs for the input list  
    while p2 <=l:
        compare.string(L[p1], L[p2], method='jarowinkler',threshold = TT, label=L[p1])
        p1+=2
        p2+=2
    features = compare.compute(candidate_links,df1, df2)
    return features




def Matching(query1,query2, SS,TT, service_account, project_id, querycolumns):

    # Connections

    # with open('service_account.json', "w") as outfile:
    #     json.dump(service_account, outfile)

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account)
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials = credentials, project = service_account['project_id'])

    # client = bigquery.Client(project= project_id)
    # os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= 'service_account.json'
    

        #  if os.path.exists("service_account.json"):
        #     os.remove("service_account.json")

    # client = Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json', project=project_id)

    
    # credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('service_account.json')
    # client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)
    SS=int(SS)
    TT=float(TT)
    
    df1 = gcp2df("""{}""".format(query1), client)
    df2 = gcp2df("""{}""".format(query2), client)

    # dumb_dict = {
    #     "dumb":"dumb"
    # }
    # with open('dumb.json', "w") as outfile:
    #     json.dump(dumb_dict, outfile)
    # os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]= 'dumb.json'

    querycolumns = json.loads(querycolumns)
    querycolumns = list(querycolumns.values())
    features = pair(df1, df2, TT, querycolumns)
    features['Similarity_score'] = features.sum(axis=1)
    features = features[features['Similarity_score']>=SS].reset_index()
    final =  features[['level_0', 'level_1']]
    final.rename(columns= {'level_0':'df1_index', 'level_1':'df2_index'}, inplace= True)
    final['Unique_ID'] = [uuid.uuid4() for _ in range(len(final.index))]
    final['Unique_ID'] = final['Unique_ID'].astype(str)
    final['Similarity_Score'] = SS
    final_duplicates = final['df1_index'].value_counts().max()
    # insert(final,"test-ahmed-project.Record_Linkage.Matching_Indices")
    message = "Mission accomplished!, your highest duplica is  " + str(final_duplicates) 
    os.remove("service_account.json")
    return {'message':message, 'final':json.loads(final.to_json()),  'df1':json.loads(df1.to_json()), 'df2':json.loads(df2.to_json())}
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__       
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app       
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app       
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Final_Coud_Run_Example\main.py", line 28, in query
    result = Matching(params['query1'],params['query2'], params['SS'],params['TT'], params['service_account'], params['project_id'], params['querycolumns'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Final_Coud_Run_Example\Record_Matching.py", line 75, in Matching
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Credentials'
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2022 18:50:01] "GET /query HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__       
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app       
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app       
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Coud_Run_Example\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Final_Coud_Run_Example\main.py", line 28, in query
    result = Matching(params['query1'],params['query2'], params['SS'],params['TT'], params['service_account'], params['project_id'], params['querycolumns'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Datalaksa\Tzu Ming\Flask exploring\Final_Coud_Run_Example\Record_Matching.py", line 75, in Matching
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Credentials'
```

I tried using using a  service account without a json file path, I'm expecting my code to accept the service account as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you use the same variable name on your import and parameter name on `Matching()` function. Your import currently looks like this:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

Then on your function `Matching()`, you accept a parameter named `service_account`. Your code references the parameter and not the import. Your function currently looks like this:

```
def Matching(query1,query2, SS,TT, service_account, project_id, querycolumns):
    ...
    ...
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account)
```

To fix this, change the name of your parameter in `Matching()` so your code won't be confused which object to use. You can rewrite your function this way:

```
def Matching(query1,query2, SS,TT, sa, project_id, querycolumns):
    ...
    ...
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(sa)
```